# How to include <tr> element in angular directive (transclude)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to include `<tr>` and `<td>` and apparently I can't do that with directive. It keeps ignoring `<td>` or `<td>` as if they don't exists. here's what I trying to accomplish:

```
<my-table>
   <tr>
     <td>hello</td>
     <td>world</td>
   </tr>
</my-table>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}])
.directive('myTable', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     transclude: true,
     templateUrl: 'my-table.html'
   };
});
```

my-table.html :

```
<table ng-transclude>

</table>
```

the code above resulted in:

```
<my-table class="ng-isolate-scope"><table ng-transclude="">

   hello  <-- no <tr> nor <td> here just plain text
   world

</table></my-table>
```

example : [PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/0ShOpcRz1aVTFEKeQe35?p=preview)

Comment: Those `<tr>` and `<td>` should be placed inside `my-dialog-close.html`.

Comment: @RogerNg that's exactly what I don't want. I want a customizable  `<tr>` but I want it to be wrapped by my directive. image it as an alternative to `<table>`

Comment: a tr without the table will be invalid html. This is the reason its taking it as a text bt not html

Comment: that summed it all up, that's why I got warning in my plunkr code before. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a transclude problem. It's a problem with invalid html, because `<tr>` without a table is invalid. So angular gets from a browser `text`, not DOM elements. So you need to have `<table>` tag inside an html:

```
  <my-table>
  <table>
      <tr>
       <td>hello</td>
       <td>world</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  </my-table>
```

Then you'll be able to get access to `tbody` element created by a browser along with `tr`'s in link function and process it:

```
  link: function(scope,element,attrs,ctrls,transclude) {
    var html = transclude();
    element.find('table').append(html[1].firstElementChild);
  }
```

or use `ng-transclude` in your template as you did. However, I may presume that you'll want to reuse the transcluded part later, so accessing it in link function makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Adding into my comment earlier, you can achieve somewhat similar like this  this if you wan to use ng-trasclude

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  }])
  .directive('myTable', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        'close': '&onClose'
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-dialog-close.html'
    };
  });
```

template

index.html

```
<my-table>
    <table>
     <tr>
       <td>hello</td>
       <td>world</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </my-table>
```

Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/u85h0sJL50k2gESfI6RT?p=preview