# AngularJS 1.5 component ng-repeat display as table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components, angularjs-1.5

How to display `ng-repeat` in a component as a table? Why is my item component not displaying data as table rows?

Here's a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MYsNMxP1bOulB7YGIGzp?p=preview) and the code as well:

index.html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <item data="name" ng-repeat="name in vm.names"></item>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

item.html

```
<tr>
  <td>{{$ctrl.data.first}}</td>
  <td>{{$ctrl.data.family}}</td>
</tr>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.names = [{family: "dela cruz", first: "juan"}, {family: "tamad", first: "juan"}]
});

angular.module('plunker').component('item', {
   templateUrl: 'item.html',
   bindings: {
     data: '='
   }
});
```

Comment: It happens because `<tr>...</tr>` outside of `tbody` is invalid `html` and a browser strips the tags. Angular doesn't get a chance to see `tr` at all

Comment: @maximus, how come it is outside when I the `<item>` component is inside the `<tbody>` tag?

Comment: when angular loads and evaluates the template before inserting them into `tbody`\

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40779707/2545680)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the  element is kept within the table and tends to break standard HTML table -> tbody -> tr -> td structure.

For this particular case, I would do the following:

```js
angular
  .module('sampleApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.names = [{family: "dela cruz", first: "juan"}, {family: "tamad", first: "juan"}];
  })
  .component('nameTable', {
     template: [
      '<table border="1">',
      '<tbody>',
      '<tr ng-repeat="name in $ctrl.data">',
      '<td>{{name.first}}</td>',
      '<td>{{name.family}}</td>',
      '</tr>',
      '</tbody>',
      '</table>'
     ].join(''),
     bindings: {
       data: '<'
     }
  });
```

```html
<body ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <name-table data="vm.names" ></name-table>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of hard-coded html on the `template`, I created an `item.html` and dump the html codes there. It works now! Thanks!